# When should I open a particular envelope in Risk Legacy?

Tags: risk-legacy

Risk Legacy, oddly enough, has *spoilers*, so I'll go ahead and use the spoiler tags.

**Description of the envelope:**

> There is an envelope in Risk Legacy, hidden in the box, marked "Do not open. Ever."

This game is intended to be played 15 times over its lifetime, after which it gets (in theory) locked down in a playable, final state.  My question is about when to open this envelope.

**Question about when to open it:**

> Obviously I want to open it sometime.  I mean, they told me *not* to open it, so *of course* I want to open it.  The question is: when?
>  Should we wait until after the 15 games are played?  Or should we open it sometime near the end, say after 12 or 13 plays?

Answers without spoilers as to the contents of the envelope are of course preferred.

Answer (score 11):

It would be difficult to go into the reasoning without spoiling anything, but you should probably open it before the 15th signature. Waiting until after that will make some of the packet not matter.

The designer's opinion, RobDaviau wrote:

> I would open at least two envelopes and one pocket first.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least a few different versions of this packet and they all do something to modify the game play in one way or the other.

I guess I'll have to answer the question with a question: Do you want to "upset" the status quo? If so, open it.

But an even better question: Are you afraid that it might turn things upside down? If so, definitely open it!

If you're afraid, then that makes the envelope exciting and if the game's becoming humdrum you need to open it too. Otherwise, open it after the 17th game or so.